# IncompatibleClassChangeError under Debezium Mysql connector Parser

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-error-1064, debezium

I have a java application in which I am using Debezium-connector-mysql dependency
like this

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>io.debezium</groupId>
            <artifactId>debezium-connector-mysql</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.CR2</version>
    </dependency>
```

when I try to run my integration test manually its working up.. and I'm  not getting any exception but when I try to build the project with

---

mvn clean install

---

I gets the below exception, can anyone help me with this

```
[2020-06-22 15:30:43,511] INFO [debezium-mysql-source|task-0] Writes to MySQL tables prevented for a total of 00:00:01.185 (io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader:777)
[2020-06-22 15:30:43,513] ERROR [debezium-mysql-source|task-0] Failed due to error: Aborting snapshot due to error when last running 'UNLOCK TABLES': io.debezium.ddl.parser.mysql.generated.MySqlParser and io.debezium.ddl.parser.mysql.generated.MySqlParser$StringDataTypeContext disagree on InnerClasses attribute (io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader:208)
io.debezium.ddl.parser.mysql.generated.MySqlParser and io.debezium.ddl.parser.mysql.generated.MySqlParser$StringDataTypeContext disagree on InnerClasses attribute
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.AbstractReader.wrap(AbstractReader.java:230)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.AbstractReader.failed(AbstractReader.java:207)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader.execute(SnapshotReader.java:831)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: io.debezium.ddl.parser.mysql.generated.MySqlParser and io.debezium.ddl.parser.mysql.generated.MySqlParser$StringDataTypeContext disagree on InnerClasses attribute
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaringClass0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaringClass(Class.java:1235)
        at java.lang.Class.getEnclosingClass(Class.java:1277)
        at java.lang.Class.getCanonicalName(Class.java:1392)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.antlr.MySqlAntlrDdlParser.initializeDataTypeResolver(MySqlAntlrDdlParser.java:100)
        at io.debezium.antlr.AntlrDdlParser.parse(AntlrDdlParser.java:72)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlSchema.applyDdl(MySqlSchema.java:314)
        at io.debezium.connector.mysql.SnapshotReader.execute(SnapshotReader.java:488)
        ... 3 more
[2020-06-22 15:30:43,592] INFO [debezium-mysql-source|task-0] WorkerSourceTask{id=debezium-mysql-source-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:478)
```

Is there anything I m doing wrong while importing the maven dependency or it is something else..!

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to pull in all Debezium artifacts in exactly the same version. Here you likely have different versions of *debezium-connector-mysql* and *debezium-ddl-parser*.

Comment: didn't worked..! 
I tried with same version of debezium-connector-mysql, debezium-core and debezium-ddl-parser
the issue still persists